# Performance issue after upgrading to neo4j 2.0 RC1

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

We have a java application that embeds neo4j server. This application loads some data from Oracle db, creates the graph and then users can do domain specific traversals and algorithms on demand.

We recently upgraded from 1.9.3 to 2.0 RC1. We are now using Schema and unique constraints as follows:

```
Iterator<ConstraintDefinition> constraints = schema.getConstraints(
                DynamicLabel.label(label)).iterator();
        if (constraints == null || !constraints.hasNext()) {
            try {
                schema.constraintFor(
                        DynamicLabel.label(label))
                        .assertPropertyIsUnique(propertyName).create();
            } catch (org.neo4j.graphdb.ConstraintViolationException ex) {
                LOG.error("CONSTRAINT ALREADY DEFINED ON: "
                        + label);
            }
        }
```

The issue is our applications startup time has become 10 times slower. Sampling the cpu times reveal the following:

[image: jview capture]

Comment: Do you have a more detailed breakdown of the measurement? Or even the full dump from JVisualVM or FlightRecorder/Mission Control? Also do you have more code than the snippet listed available? Would love to investigate this? What else do you do during startup??

Comment: Sure, I can gather the dump and share as much code as you would like to see. We block everything till the graph is completely ready so, only thing going on at that point is 10^4 nodes getting committed in each transaction. (Data from the nodes is coming from our present system of record). Thanks !

Comment: Attached the visualvm snapshot to the google groups post. More coming !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We instrumented the application and found the root cause of the slowness. Following thread will discuss the specific issue we found in detail:

[How to improve performance while committing nodes in bulk with Neo4j 2.0 RC1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409870/how-to-improve-performance-while-committing-nodes-in-bulk-with-neo4j-2-0-rc1)