# How to improve performance while committing nodes in bulk with Neo4j 2.0 RC1?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

I am interested to know if the program(below) can be improved to perform faster. Seems like, a lot of time is spent in Transaction's close() when we have constraints in place (**90 secs with constraint**, and **1 sec without**)

[image]

Following is the output of the program:

```
2013-12-05 14:30:20,399 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 1 #############
2013-12-05 14:30:20,399 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:30:45,296 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 24897
2013-12-05 14:30:45,296 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:32:20,372 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 95076
2013-12-05 14:32:20,372 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 2 #############
2013-12-05 14:32:20,372 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:32:47,168 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 26796
2013-12-05 14:32:47,168 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:34:16,040 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 88872
2013-12-05 14:34:16,040 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 3 #############
2013-12-05 14:34:16,040 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:34:44,423 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 28383
2013-12-05 14:34:44,423 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:36:16,964 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 92541
2013-12-05 14:36:16,964 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 4 #############
2013-12-05 14:36:16,964 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:36:43,376 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 26412
2013-12-05 14:36:43,376 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:38:13,156 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 89780
2013-12-05 14:38:13,156 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 5 #############
2013-12-05 14:38:13,156 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:38:39,459 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 26303
2013-12-05 14:38:39,459 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 14:40:10,581 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 91122
2013-12-05 14:40:10,582 [Thread-5] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ### GRAPHDB SHUTDOWNHOOK INVOKED !!!
```

Following is the test program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.ConstraintDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;

public class Lab {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Lab.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("graphdb"));
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("graphdb")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.use_memory_mapped_buffers, "true")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs, "false").setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.query_cache_size, "1000")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_grab_size, "1000").newGraphDatabase();

        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
            createConstraint(schema, "TEST", "COUNT");
            tx.success();
        }

        int count = 0;
        long time;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            LOG.info("############# WAVE " + i + " #############");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
            LOG.info("TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            try {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int j = 1; j <= 10000; j++) {
                    count++;
                    Node n = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("TEST"));
                    n.setProperty("COUNT", count);
                }
                LOG.info("TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                tx.success();
                LOG.info("TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            } finally {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                tx.close();
                LOG.info("TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createConstraint(Schema schema, String label, String propertyName) {
        Iterator<ConstraintDefinition> constraints = schema.getConstraints(DynamicLabel.label(label)).iterator();
        if (constraints == null || !constraints.hasNext()) {
            try {
                schema.constraintFor(DynamicLabel.label(label)).assertPropertyIsUnique(propertyName).create();
            } catch (org.neo4j.graphdb.ConstraintViolationException ex) {
                LOG.error("CONSTRAINT ALREADY DEFINED ON: " + label);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LOG.info("### GRAPHDB SHUTDOWNHOOK INVOKED !!!");
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

***I commented the call to createConstraint() and following is the output of the program:***

```
2013-12-05 15:34:34,686 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 1 #############
2013-12-05 15:34:34,686 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:35,529 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 843
2013-12-05 15:34:35,529 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:37,635 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 2106
2013-12-05 15:34:37,635 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 2 #############
2013-12-05 15:34:37,635 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:37,729 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 94
2013-12-05 15:34:37,729 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:38,915 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 1186
2013-12-05 15:34:38,915 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 3 #############
2013-12-05 15:34:38,915 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:38,963 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 48
2013-12-05 15:34:38,963 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:39,684 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 721
2013-12-05 15:34:39,684 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 4 #############
2013-12-05 15:34:39,684 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:39,715 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 31
2013-12-05 15:34:39,715 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:40,464 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 749
2013-12-05 15:34:40,464 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 5 #############
2013-12-05 15:34:40,464 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:40,527 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 63
2013-12-05 15:34:40,527 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-05 15:34:41,416 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 889
2013-12-05 15:34:41,432 [Thread-4] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ### GRAPHDB SHUTDOWNHOOK INVOKED !!!
```

Comment: Replacing the constraint with a simple index and looking up existence before insert changes the commit() time to a second while keeping the insert time almost the same. Should i just dump Constraint or, will it be improved further ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, simply the index writer flushing too often. See commit https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/dcc72fa83e0f3742c9ddebaad625254b9f3c9404

Comment: i would love to try this out. Did it make into the stable release ?

Comment: No, it's not the stable release.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but test with that patch and update SO with the new values if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing constraints with use of pessimistic locking and doing our own lookup increases the node creation time to 50 secs. But the commit time is under 2 secs. This(50 + 2) is still much better than the 90 + 25 secs with Constraints.

**Should i go with this approach ?**

Output:

```
2013-12-06 12:01:39,535 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 1 #############
2013-12-06 12:01:39,544 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:02:30,505 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 50961
2013-12-06 12:02:30,505 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:02:33,020 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 2515
2013-12-06 12:02:33,020 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 2 #############
2013-12-06 12:02:33,020 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:03:16,146 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 43126
2013-12-06 12:03:16,146 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:03:17,241 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 1095
2013-12-06 12:03:17,241 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 3 #############
2013-12-06 12:03:17,241 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:04:00,194 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 42953
2013-12-06 12:04:00,194 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:04:01,019 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 825
2013-12-06 12:04:01,019 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 4 #############
2013-12-06 12:04:01,019 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:04:45,073 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 44054
2013-12-06 12:04:45,073 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:04:45,932 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 859
2013-12-06 12:04:45,932 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ############# WAVE 5 #############
2013-12-06 12:04:45,932 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:05:29,401 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): 43468
2013-12-06 12:05:29,401 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): 0
2013-12-06 12:05:30,182 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): 781
2013-12-06 12:05:30,183 [Thread-4] INFO  net.ahm.graph.Lab  - ### GRAPHDB SHUTDOWNHOOK INVOKED !!!
```

source code:

```
package net.ahm.graph;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterable;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.ConstraintDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;

public class Lab {
    private static final String TEST_PROPERTY = "COUNT";
    private static final String TEST_LABEL = "TEST";
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Lab.class);

    private static Node lockNode = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("graphdb"));
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("graphdb")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.use_memory_mapped_buffers, "true")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs, "false").setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.query_cache_size, "1000")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_grab_size, "1000").newGraphDatabase();

        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);

        /*
         * try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
         * Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
         * createConstraint(schema, "TEST", "COUNT");
         * tx.success();
         * }
         */

        createIndex(TEST_LABEL, TEST_PROPERTY, graphDb);

        int count = 0;
        long time;

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            lockNode = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("LOCKNODE"));
            tx.success();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            LOG.info("############# WAVE " + i + " #############");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
            LOG.info("TIME TO BEGIN TX (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            try {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int j = 1; j <= 10000; j++) {
                    count++;
                    if (findNode(TEST_LABEL, TEST_PROPERTY, count, graphDb) == null) {
                        tx.acquireWriteLock(lockNode);
                        if (findNode(TEST_LABEL, TEST_PROPERTY, count, graphDb) == null) {
                            Node n = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label(TEST_LABEL));
                            n.setProperty(TEST_PROPERTY, count);
                        } else {
                            LOG.error("NODE WITH PROPERTY ALREADY EXISTS: " + count);
                        }
                    } else {
                        LOG.error("NODE WITH PROPERTY ALREADY EXISTS: " + count);
                    }
                }
                LOG.info("TIME TO CREATE 10000 nodes (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                tx.success();
                LOG.info("TIME TO MARK SUCCESS (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            } finally {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                tx.close();
                LOG.info("TIME TO COMMIT (m-sec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createConstraint(Schema schema, String label, String propertyName) {
        Iterator<ConstraintDefinition> constraints = schema.getConstraints(DynamicLabel.label(label)).iterator();
        if (constraints == null || !constraints.hasNext()) {
            try {
                schema.constraintFor(DynamicLabel.label(label)).assertPropertyIsUnique(propertyName).create();
            } catch (org.neo4j.graphdb.ConstraintViolationException ex) {
                LOG.error("CONSTRAINT ALREADY DEFINED ON: " + label);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createIndex(String label, String propertyName, GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {

        IndexDefinition indexDefinition;
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
            indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label(label)).on(propertyName).create();
            tx.success();
        }

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
            schema.awaitIndexOnline(indexDefinition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            tx.success();
        }

    }

    private static Node findNode(String sLabel, String propertyName, Object propertyValue, GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        if (propertyValue != null) {
            Label label = DynamicLabel.label(sLabel);
            ResourceIterable<Node> ri = graphDb.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label, propertyName, propertyValue);
            if (ri != null) {
                try {
                    ResourceIterator<Node> iter = ri.iterator();
                    if (iter != null && iter.hasNext()) {
                        return iter.next();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("ERROR WHILE FINDING ID: " + propertyValue + " , LABEL: " + sLabel + " , PROPERTY: " + propertyName, e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LOG.info("### GRAPHDB SHUTDOWNHOOK INVOKED !!!");
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: See my answer above. It's too late for 2.0 GA to have this fix, but a 2.0.1 will contain it.

Comment: Thank you Mattias, will wait for 2.0.1 with bated breath. You are a rockstar !!